# FFMPEG: At least one output file must be specified

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to split a video from a URL.... this is my CMD command:

```sh
ffmpeg -i 'https://mediasite-ondemand.maastrichtuniversity.nl/MediasiteDeliver/ondemand/MP4Video/90e0ea3d-4087-4a3d-8a78-7acf7906c4cb.mp4?playbackTicket=fb14f2f3baf84412bc6463d4e312ec27&site=mediasite.maastrichtuniversity.nl' -ss 00:00:00 -t 0:25:00 -c copy  SplicedVid.wav
```

Why does it return:

'site' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

My version:

```
ffmpeg -version output:
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2020-11-19-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp
--enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-
libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llv
m --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable
-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
```

Comment: It seems like you had a line break in your comment. I fixed it in your question, tried it and at least for me it's now working

Comment: Still won't work, but thanks for the edit in my post.

Comment: Does it work if you escape some characters like the following? `ffmpeg -i https://mediasite-ondemand.maastrichtuniversity.nl/MediasiteDeliver/ondemand/MP4Video/90e0ea3d-4087-4a3d-8a78-7acf7906c4cb.mp4\?playbackTicket\=fb14f2f3baf84412bc6463d4e312ec27\&site\=mediasite.maastrichtuniversity.nl -ss 00:00:00 -t 0:25:00 -c copy SplicedVid.wav`

Comment: "Invalid data found when processing input"

Comment: Can you add your ffmpeg version to your post? (with `ffmpeg -version`) and maybe also the complete output of ffmpeg instead of only the few lines, if they are some lines?

Comment: @em0lar sure, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the URL in quotes:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://mediasite-ondemand.maastrichtuniversity.nl/MediasiteDeliver/ondemand/MP4Video/90e0ea3d-4087-4a3d-8a78-7acf7906c4cb.mp4?playbackTicket=fb14f2f3baf84412bc6463d4e312ec27&site=mediasite.maastrichtuniversity.nl" -t 00:25:00 output.wav
```

Comment: now it returns only: 'site' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @JeroenWeber Maybe Windows doesn't like single quotes. Try double quotes.